# Jfrog artifactory cli

Tags: jfrog-cli

you I am trying to pass two `${key}` values in a file spec. Is there any way I can call these two `${key}` values through jfrog `cli` command?

E.g., I have tried the following command

```
sh "./jfrog rt s --spec compare.spec  --spec-vars currentBuild=${currentBuild.number};previousBuild=${currentBuild.previousBuild.number}"
```

But it is displaying output only for one value.

Answer (score 0):

The command is missing quotes surrounding the spec-vars. So for example with a spec file like

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "${pat}/",
            "target": "${tgt}/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to run the command as

```
jfrog rt dl --spec otherspec --spec-vars "pat=generic-local;tgt=local"
```

To make sure that I download the files from the "generic-local" repository to a folder called "local"

If you execute the command with `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG`, the output will display both the spec file you provided as well as the resolved file:

```
$ JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG jfrog rt dl --spec otherspec --spec-vars "pat=generic-local;tgt=local"
[Debug] Replacing variables in the provided File Spec:
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "${pat}/",
            "target": "${tgt}/"
        }
    ]
}
[Debug] Replacing '${pat}' with 'generic-local'
[Debug] Replacing '${tgt}' with 'local'
[Debug] The reformatted File Spec is:
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "generic-local/",
            "target": "local/"
        }
    ]
}
[Info] Searching items to download...
```